# illegal start of expression invert if

Tags: java, netbeans, condiciones, else

Estoy programando en Java, soy nuevo en este lenguaje. Al intentar ejecutar el siguiente código me muestra el error de "illegal start of expression invert if"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HolaMundo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Proporcione un valor entre 0 y 10 ");
        int calificacion = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        if(calificacion == 0){
        System.out.println("F");
        }
        else {if(calificacion == 1  && < 6){
            System.out.println("F");
        }
        else if(calificacion == 6 && <= 7){
            System.out.println("D");
        }
        else if(calificacion == 7 && <= 8){
                System.out.println("C");
        }
        else if(calificacion == 8 && <= 9){
                System.out.println("B");
        }
        else if(calificacion == 9 && <= 10){
                System.out.println("A");
        }

    }
}
```

Mil gracias

Comment: Es un error tipografico aqúí : else {if(calificacion == 1  && < 6){ , no debe llevar el primer {, es super importante revisar: [If else, if else if Java. Estructura o esquema de decisión condicional.](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=481:if-else-if-else-if-java-estructura-o-esquema-de-decision-condicional-ejemplos-de-uso-ejercicios-cu00636b&catid=68&Itemid=188)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira aquí te dejo otra opción para tu código, como estas haciendo validaciones con calificaciones decidí declarar la variable "calificacion" como float en vez de int para que te permita ingresar puntos decimales.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Proporcione un valor entre 0 y 10 ");
    float calificacion = Float.parseFloat(scanner.nextLine());

        if(calificacion < 6 ){
            System.out.println("F");
        }else{
            if(calificacion >= 6 && calificacion < 7){
                System.out.println("D");
            }
            if(calificacion >= 7 && calificacion < 8){
                System.out.println("C");
            }
            if(calificacion >= 8 && calificacion < 9){
                System.out.println("B");
            }
            if(calificacion >= 9 && calificacion <= 10){
                System.out.println("A");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justamente estaba pensando en ello. Eres muy amable

Answer (score 2):

Me alegro de que te hayas animado a aprender Java, considera dos puntos:

1. **Identar el código.** Tienes un else if dónde te falta un corchete. (el primero para ser concretos)
2. **Las comparaciones usando operadores lógicos, AND, OR, etc...** Si quieres comparar algo, debes poner explícitamente la comparación, la sintaxis de Java no está creada para explicitar sólo la primera vez la variable a comparar y a partir de ahí, anidar condiciones indiferentemente, visualmente:

```js
else if(calificacion == 9 && <= 10){ // Incorrecto
```

```js
else if(calificacion == 9 && calificacion <= 10){ // Correcto
```

De forma que tu código escrito de forma correcta sería:

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Proporcione un valor entre 0 y 10 ");
    int calificacion = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

    if(calificacion == 0){
        System.out.println("F");
    }
    else {
        if(calificacion == 1  && calificacion < 6){
            System.out.println("F");
        }
        else if(calificacion == 6 && calificacion <= 7){
            System.out.println("D");
        }
        else if(calificacion == 7 && calificacion <= 8){
                System.out.println("C");
        }
        else if(calificacion == 8 && calificacion <= 9){
                System.out.println("B");
        }
        else if(calificacion == 9 && calificacion <= 10){
                System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

}
```

Aunque podríamos refactorizar esto un poco, para que sea más limpio y fácil de extender sus funcionalidades (además de que tienes algunos fallos de lógica, si introduzco un 7, van a saltar dos mensajes a la vez, fijate en los condicionales que has puesto, mismo ocurriría con el 8 y el 9):

```js
if(calificacion < 6){
    System.out.println("F");
} else if (calificacion >= 6 && calificacion <= 7) {
    System.out.println("D");
} else if (calificacion > 7 && calificacion <= 8){
    System.out.println("C");
} else if (calificacion > 8 && calificacion <= 9){
    System.out.println("B");
} else if (calificacion > 9 && calificacion <= 10){
    System.out.println("A");
}
```

Comment: muchas Gracias a todos quedó comprendido, son muy amables.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error tipográfico aquí:

```
     else {if(calificacion == 1  && < 6){
```

debe ser y dentro escribir las condiciones:

```
    else if(......){
```

pero además las condiciones deben ser:

```
 else if (calificacion == 1  && calificacion < 6) {
```

ya que usas && para conectar cada condición esta debe ser especificada entre que valores se realizaría.

---

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Proporcione un valor entre 0 y 10 ");
    int calificacion = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

    if(calificacion == 0){
    System.out.println("F");
    } else if(calificacion == 1  && calificacion < 6){
        System.out.println("F");
    } else if(calificacion == 6 && calificacion <= 7){
        System.out.println("D");
    } else if(calificacion == 7 && calificacion <= 8){
            System.out.println("C");
    } else if(calificacion == 8 && calificacion <= 9){
            System.out.println("B");
    } else if(calificacion == 9 && calificacion <= 10){
            System.out.println("A");
    }
```

Te sugiero revises

[Identación y llaves: ¿cómo y cuando usarlas?](https://dcodingames.com/identacion-y-llaves/)

[If else, if else if Java. Estructura o esquema de decisión condicional.](http://else%20if(calificacion%20==%209%20&&%20%3C=%2010)%7B%20//%20Correcto)

[Declaración if, else if](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)